# IOKit get current power source

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, iokit

How do I get the current power source on a Mac, using `IOKit`?

I want to see if the Mac is running via the built-in battery or via a power adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions in [IOPowerSources.h](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOPowerSources_header_reference/Reference/reference.html) (specifically, `IOPSGetProvidingPowerSourceType()`) will give you the info you're looking for.